# Can I point the necessary codepage for the individual string variable in the `Watch1` window?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, codepages

Visual Studio 2015, C++ language, debugging.

In the `Watch1` window I look the values of my variables (strings) of the `wchar_t*` and `char*` types. The first of them is `Unicode` and the second is `ANSI` (`CP_OEMCP` codepage). In the `Watch1` window the text of the `wchar_t*` variable is displaying correctly, but the text of the `char*` variable is displaying unreadable. Can I point the necessary codepage for the individual string variable in the `Watch1` window? I want to see both values of my strings correctly in the `Watch1` window.

Maybe for such cases is exists the some syntax, similar the `$err,hr` (the text of the last error, which  was gotten via the `GetLastError()` function).

**UPD** (the screen added)

[image]

Console window has the right output, but in the memory and in the `Watch1` window I see unreadable string for my `ansiText` variable.

Comment: How come CP_OEMCP string is unreadable? Give us an example of a string that you have in memory (its hex bytes), what you expect to see, and what you actually see.

Comment: I added the screen in my topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the original string (starting with hex values 8D A0 A6) is not on Windows-1251 (Windows Cyrillic) code page, but on OEM 866 code page. These two are different, and Visual Studio expects Windows-1251, because that's system's code page (code page used for non-Unicode applications).

It is not possible to specify a code page when you watch a string in debugger. Everything inside should be Unicode anyway, or at least UTF-8, and for those two there are format specifiers, **su** and **s8**. See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75w45ekt.aspx) for all format specifiers.

What you can do is have the following function integrated in the code, and when you want to see some non-ANSI (or non-CP_ACP, to be precise) string just call this function with the string and code page as parameters (but use the function only once in Watch window):

```
LPCWSTR ViewString(LPCSTR szString, UINT nCodePage)
{
    static WCHAR szTemp[1024];
    MultiByteToWideChar(nCodePage, 0, szString, -1, szTemp, 1024);
    return szTemp;
}
```

So, in your case in Watch window instead of `(char*)ansiText` there would be `ViewString(ansiText, 866)`. Also, note that this is not actually "ANSI text", but "OEM text".

I don't know what exactly your program is supposed to do, but I would convert all non-Unicode strings to Unicode at the earliest point in code (right where you get a non-Unicode string), and in your code always work just with Unicode strings. To convert OEM 866 string to Unicode you can use function `MultiByteToWideChar` with `CodePage` parameter = 866.